# My PostgreSQL server looks like has wrong UTC timestamp

Tags: postgresql

My PostgreSQL server looks like has wrong UTC timestamp.

```
$ date -u +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S
2021-08-18T19:46:37
$ node -e "console.log((new Date()).toISOString())"
2021-08-18T19:46:53.754Z
$ psql -c "SELECT current_setting('TIMEZONE');"
 current_setting
-----------------
 Europe/Berlin
(1 row)
$ psql -c "SELECT cast(to_char (now()::timestamp at time zone 'UTC', 'YYYY-MM-DDT HH24:MI:SS') as varchar)"
 to_char
----------------------
 2021-08-18T 23:47:15
(1 row)
```

Berlin is two hours from UTC, but should return 19 not 23 in the hour part.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Two comments 1) You don't need the `cast(` as `to_char` does that. 2) Try with `now()`. You are getting a double conversion otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

To illustrate the issue, explanation in line:

```
set timezone='Europe/Berlin';

--Returns a timestamp with time zone.
select now();
              now              
-------------------------------
 2021-08-18 23:19:01.421586+02

--Correctly uses the time zone information to get UTC.
select now() at time zone 'UTC';
timezone          
----------------------------
 2021-08-18 21:19:05.010232

--Converts now() to non-timezone value. This is where the 
--issue starts.
select now()::timestamp;
now             
----------------------------
 2021-08-18 23:19:19.276691

--Postgres takes the non-timezone value takes to be a 'UTC' value
--and then rotates that to timezone('Europe/Berlin') time.
--So 2021-08-18 23:19:19.276691 UTC is 2021-08-19 01:19:36.20278+02 --Europe/Berlin
select now()::timestamp at time zone 'UTC';
timezone           
------------------------------
 2021-08-19 01:19:36.20278+02
```